# Taking derivative with nested sigma notations

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm having some difficulty taking the derivative of the following expression with respect to $b_j^i$:

Note that $b_j^i$ does NOT mean $b_j$ raised to the power of $i$. It is simply one of the terms.

$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^M||\sum\limits_{j=1}^Na_j + \sum\limits_{j=1}^N(a_j*b_j^i)||^2
$$

Can anyone give me some hint on how to do this?

Thanks

===
More detail, both $a$ and $b$ are vectors.

Comment: Since the sum "inside" the double bars is presumably just a real number, why the double bars? Does it mean absolute value? (If so such double bars typically go around vectors, not scalars.)

Comment: If $a,b$ are vectors, it is still the case that e.g. $a_1,a_2...$ are scalars, provided you mean as usual for subscripts to mean components. So my above question on the double bars still applies.

Comment: One more thing: since $b$ has lower *and* upper subscripts, and the superscripts are not indicating powers, it looks like $b$ is really an $N \times N$ matrix rather than a vector, Perhaps it would help if you gave background about what the double sum means, where it "comes from".

Answer (score 0):

$\frac d {dt} \| v \|^2 = \frac d {dt} \langle v, v \rangle = \langle \frac{dv}{dt}, v\rangle + \langle v, \frac{dv}{dt} \rangle$. How you simplify further depends on the field.